# understanding shapes for Keras model

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to wrap my head around the shape needed for my specific task. I am attempting to train a qlearner on some time series data which is contained in a dataframe. My dataframe has the following columns: open, close, high, low and I am trying to get a sliding window of say 50x timesteps. Here is example code for each window:

```
window = df.iloc[0:50]

df_norm = (window - window.mean()) / (window.max() - window.min())

x = df_norm.values
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
print x.shape
#(1,50, 4)
```

Now that I know my shape is (1,50,4) for each item in X I'm at a loss for what shape I feed my model. Lets say I have the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(50,4)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(num_actions))
```

Gives the following error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (50,4) into shape (1,50)
```

And here is another attempt:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(hidden_size, input_shape=(50,4), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_actions))
model.compile(sgd(lr=.2), "mse")
```

which gives the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (50,4) into shape (1,50))
```

Here is the shape the model is expecting and the state from my env:

```
print "Inputs: {}".format(model.input_shape)
print "actual: {}".format(env.state.shape)
#Inputs: (None, 50, 4)
#actual: (1, 50, 4)
```

Can someone explain where I am going wrong with the shapes here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrent layer takes inputs of shape `(batch_size, timesteps, input_features)`. Since the shape of `x` is `(1, 50, 4)`, the data should be interpreted as a single batch of 50 timesteps, each containing 4 features. When initializing the first layer of a model, you pass an `input_shape`: a tuple specifying the shape of the input, excluding the `batch_size` dimension. In the case of LSTM layers, you can pass `None` as the `timesteps` dimension. Hence, this is how the first layer of the network should be initialized:

```
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 4)))
```

The second LSTM layer is followed by a dense layer. So you don't need to return sequences for this layer. Hence, this is how you should initialize the second LSTM layer:

```
model.add(LSTM(32))
```

Every batch of 50 time steps in `x` is supposed to be mapped to a single action vector in `y`. Therefore, since the shape of `x` is `(1, 50, 4)`, the shape of `y` must be `(1, num_actions)`. Make sure `y` doesn't have the `timesteps` dimension.

Therefore, under the assumption that `x` and `y` have the right shapes, the following code should work:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 4)))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(num_actions))

model.compile(sgd(lr=.2), "mse")

# x.shape == (1, 50, 4)
# y.shape == (1, num_actions)

history = model.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try that:
     ValueError: Error when checking : expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (50, 4)

I removed the line where I expanded the dims and set the input_shape to (None, 4). 

In my code the environment's state is the (50,4) array. Should I be returning an array with a shape like (1, 50, 4) since normally I would feed a list of samples that are shapped (50,4) e.g. (500, 50, 4) where 500 is the number samples? 

Sorry if these seem like really basic questions

Comment: I am thinking that maybe I didn't make it completely clear what I was trying to do. The "x" in my example is 1 window returned by my environment which has 50x time steps with 4x features each. At each point the agent will be getting a state from the environment which has the shape (50,4). So if I were to collect a larger sample, of say 500x states, the shape would be (500, 50, 4).

Comment: @NomadCrypto, I think I figured out what it is you're struggling to realize and edited my answer accordingly. Let me know if this helps.